# update joined table using JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I 'm trying to update the value of joined item using JPQL but this doesnt work for me.

my Entity `Prof`

```
@OneToMany (cascade = ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="jnt_Prof_Exam",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idUser"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="idExam"))
    private List<Exam> exams;
```

my code for update

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("QuizPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        String req = "UPDATE Prof p SET p.exams = ?1 where p.idUser=?2";
        Query q = em.createQuery(req);
        q.setParameter(1, e);
        q.setParameter(2, idProf);
        q.executeUpdate();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
```

the shown Exception is

```
An association field cannot be used in an update item's path expression.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem's exactly what the message says: you cannot reference an association field (`p.exams` in your case) within an `UPDATE` query.

That's a rather convoluted way of establishing the association. Why not simply query `Prof` by `idUser` and set the value of `p.exams`? JPA will take care of the rest.